# Beamer: Colour Incompatibility theme Berkely and colortheme Beaver (white on grey navigation sidebar)

Tags: beamer, color, captions

I would extremely appreciate your help! :)

> When I open in Beamer `\usetheme{Berkeley}` and `\usecolortheme{beaver}` the **section titles are unreadably displayed in white on the light grey in the navigation sidebar**. 
>   This should be possible to fix, since this example claims the compatability of these two themes (https://hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/). 
>   Thank you for your help!

If you think my specific code could help you, it is the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usetheme{Berkeley}

\usecolortheme{beaver}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\section{Introduction}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you look at the linked site you'll see that the section titles are also very bright, only subsections are darker. So it is wanted behavior, if you combine those two themes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the font colour from white to whatever colour you deem to have enough contrast:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usetheme{Berkeley}

\usecolortheme{beaver}
\setbeamercolor{section in sidebar}{fg=black}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow! Impressively quick fix! Thank you very very much samcarter! :)